# PHP AQMP message format

Tags: php, queue, message-queue, amqp, php-amqp

Can I put in queue `PHP objects` or I must to [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) them before put into queue and then [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)?

How to handle messages from queues?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to use one of numerous serializers. If your app is homogenous standard php's `seraialize` and `unserialize` will works fine, otherwise you may want to use [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/json_encode) and [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/json_decode).

P.S.:

I wrote small framework to deal with amqp - [amqpy](https://github.com/pinepain/amqpy) which deal with serialization and deserialization transparently + add some sugar like advanced exceptions handling, etc. It doesn't provide enough docs and examples yet, but if someone look into sources and existent demos and find framework useful I will spend some time to add them.